# How to add a Select addon to input field in Semantic UI React?

Tags: forms, reactjs, input, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React for my React JS project. I need to add an addon to the input field, but cant do it. [image: something like that, but ideally the addon would be on the right side]

(ideally the addon would be on the right side)

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` component is a wrapper around `Dropdown`. I think that you're looking for [this example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input#variations-actions).

I also made a working example for you:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: '86', text: '+86', value: '86' },
  { key: '89', text: '+89', value: '89' },
]

const Example = () => (
  <Input 
    label={{ 
      basic: true,
      content: <Dropdown compact options={options} defaultValue='86' />
    }}
    placeholder='1234'
  />
)
```